# How to retrieve PHAsset from PHPicker?

Tags: ios, swift, phasset, phpickerviewcontroller, phpicker

In **WWDC20** apple introduced **[PHPicker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phpickerviewcontroller)** - the modern replacement for UIImagePickerController.

I'm wondering if it's possible to retrieve PHAsset using the new photo picker?

**Here is my code**:

```
private func presentPicker(filter: PHPickerFilter) {
    var configuration = PHPickerConfiguration()
    configuration.filter = filter
    configuration.selectionLimit = 0
    
    let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
    picker.delegate = self
    present(picker, animated: true)
}


func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I managed to find an answer from the developers of this framework on the [apple forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650902):

> Yes, PHPickerResult has the assetIdentifier property which can contain
> a local identifier to fetch the PHAsset from the library. To have
> PHPicker return asset identifiers, you need to initialize
> PHPickerConfiguration with the library.
>
> Please note that PHPicker does not extend the Limited Photos Library
> access for the selected items if the user put your app in Limited
> Photos Library mode. It would be a good opportunity to reconsider if
> the app really needs direct Photos Library access or can work with
> just the image and video data. But that really depend on the app.
>
> The relevant section of the "Meet the new Photos picker" session
> begins at [10m 20s](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10652/?t=620).

**Sample code for PhotoKit access looks like this:**

```
import UIKit
import PhotosUI
class PhotoKitPickerViewController: UIViewController, PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    @IBAction func presentPicker(_ sender: Any) {
            let photoLibrary = PHPhotoLibrary.shared()
            let configuration = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: photoLibrary)
            let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
            picker.delegate = self
            present(picker, animated: true)
    }
    
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
            picker.dismiss(animated: true)
            
            let identifiers = results.compactMap(\.assetIdentifier)
            let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: identifiers, options: nil)
            
            // TODO: Do something with the fetch result if you have Photos Library access
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting this, good use of self Q and A on SO.

Comment: Is it possible to obtain some meta data (like photo shot date) directly from the ItemProvider? Or as long as we need the meta, we need go through the PHAsset?

Comment: Is anyone else running into an issue where the fetchResult is always empty? The compactMap works and I get identifiers back, but the fetch result never returns any results for me.

Comment: @JKoko remember set `PHPhotoLibrary.shared()` in `PHPickerConfiguration`

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. @JKoko have you found a solution?

Comment: @JKoko It seems that you need access to All Photos, i.e. full permission in order to access a PHAsset.